# python + win32: simple way to run a process and print its error code?

Tags: python, winapi

I'm running Windows XP and want to run a process and print its exit code. I don't have a C compiler, nor do I want to use one. I do have Python though, so I figure it's probably the easiest way to do this.

How can I write a quick python script to run a process and print its exit code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

never mind, found it in the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions):

```
 import subprocess;
 retcode = subprocess.call(["ls","-l"])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) has all your answers

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> command = ['foo.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2']
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Yea, that works fine for simple calls, but more complex invocations involving reading stdout and pipes cause issues with check_call, so I always urge people to learn the semantics of Popen(...)